# Solution for database updation without hitting db after some time intervals

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

Hitting a db again and again on some time intervals is a big mess as if there are 100k users logged in db will get 1 million request every 10 seconds which i cant afford. I have researched a lot about this issue and need a perfect solution for this.
(Working in NODEJS & PostgreSQL)

Comment: If "hitting the db" is a problem, then rewrite your program to not do that. This is typically done by caching data that is retrieved from the database

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 9.4+ provides `logical decoding` which gives access to row level changes. You can listen to the write ahead log of postgres and have your application receive data as push from the database.

You may have to build a middleware that does it for you. I found a good write up that talks about utilizing `logical decoding` and `apache kafka` streams.
https://www.confluent.io/blog/bottled-water-real-time-integration-of-postgresql-and-kafka/